# Resize StackPanel to fit screen when removing ads

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, user-controls

I have a Windows Phone 8 app that has ads at the bottom of the screen.

When I remove the ad I want the area that it was occupying to be replaced with the game screen content. I've searched for this but haven't come across a solution yet, I'm sure it's something simple that I have missed!

As an example please see following code:

```
<!--Panorama item one-->
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="Level Stastics">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,88"  >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Height="Auto" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,-30" >
            <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Click Me" Click="button1_Click"/>
            <Button Content="last Button remove" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <Button Content="Button"/>
            <Button Content="Button"/>
            <Button Content="Button"/>
            <Button Content="Button"/>
            <Button Content="Button"/>
            <Button x:Name="last" Content="last Button"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</phone:PanoramaItem>
```

(Not my actual code, just an example to see how removing components works with filling the space left behind)

When I click button1 it removes the last button, but does not resize the remaining buttons to occupy the space. The `on_click` method sets the buttons's visibility to Collapsed. I assumed this removed it from the visual tree?

What I want is to have the game area (of which I have 2, one portrait and one a panoramic page) which is filled with controls and an area at the bottom of the screen which serves as the ad space (480x80). When the user buys the full product the ads are removed and the game space above the ad occupies the full screen space and resizes itself. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to be noted here:

1. The StackPanel is in first Row of the Grid whose Height is "auto". When it is in "auto", it does not allow it's content to use the remaining space. It just provides space for the content's height. Not more than that. So make that Row's height as * and make the second Row's height as auto (or remove it if not used). If 2nd row is not set to auto, both rows will share equal space/height.
2. StackPanel does not spread it's content to all the available space. It is similar to Grid "auto". So replace it with Grid and add Rows having * as height except for the last row. Last row's height should be auto because it has to be collapsed (* always allocates divided percentage of space for the row).

Try this one:

```
<Grid>

<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>

<Grid Height="Auto" Grid.Row="0" >

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" x:Name="button1" Content="Click Me" Click="button1_Click" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="last Button remove" Click="Button_Click" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Button" />
    <Button  Grid.Row="3" Content="Button" />
    <Button Grid.Row="4" Content="Button" />
    <Button Grid.Row="5" Content="Button" />
    <Button Grid.Row="6" Content="Button" />
    <Button Grid.Row="7" x:Name="last" Content="last Button" />

</Grid>
```

Hope this helps. Enjoy coding :)